# Проставить даты на кнопках автоматически JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, дата, scss

Я создал календарь с расписанием лекций/пар, вся информация **вытягивается из файлов JSON** и JS сам формирует карточки в зависимости от дня недели и элемента из json файла, пример [здесь](https://ipz-schedule.tk/).

Задача состоит в том, чтобы не вытягивать из файлов json даты, а проставлять их автоматически на кнопках. Я вынес отдельно эту задачу на Codepen, 2 день не могу понять как сделать автоматическое проставление дат. Текущую дату я могу отследить и отформатировать в виде (день недели, число, месяц, год) но только на 1 день...

Исходники Codepen [тут](https://codepen.io/MrGregor_228/pen/XWKWQyY)

```
 <nav class="schedule-navigation-panel">
            <ul>
                <li><button>Пн<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Вт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Ср<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Чт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Пт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Сб<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
                <li><button>Вс<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="week-cont">
                <div class="numerator">Числитель</div>
                <div class="denumerator">Знаменатель</div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap";
button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}
.schedule-navigation-panel {
        ul {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;

            @media screen and (max-width:660px) {
                li {
                    flex: 1 1 33%;
                    padding: 5px;

                    @media screen and (max-width:350px) {
                        flex: 1 1 50%;
                    }

                    @media screen and (max-width:250px) {
                        flex: 1 1 100%;
                    }

                    button {
                        width: 100%;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray;
                    }
                }                
            }

            li {
                &.active {
                    button {
                        background-color: #1ba4ee;
                        color: white;
                    }
                }

                button {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
                    flex-basis: auto;
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    background-color: #f7f7f7;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding: 5px 10px;
                    line-height: 1;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray, inset 0 0 0px gray, 0px 2px 20px lightgray;
                    transition: .15s linear;

                    &:active {
                        top: 3px;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray, inset 0 0 10px gray, 0px 2px 10px lightgray;
                    }

                    span {
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-weight: 200;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .week-cont {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            .numerator {
                margin-right: 5px;
            }

            .denumerator {
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
            .numerator,
            .denumerator {
                margin-top: 25px;
                text-align: center;
                flex: 1 1 50%;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 10px;

                &.active {
                    background-color: green;
                    color: white;
                }
                @media screen and (max-width:660px) {
                    
                        &.numerator {
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            margin-left: 5px;
                        }
    
                        &.denumerator {
                            margin-left: 5px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                        }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Это попытки на JS сделать отображение хотя бы текущей даты...

```
let nowDate = new Date(),
    today = nowDate.toLocaleString('ru',{day:"numeric", month:"short", year:"numeric", weekday: "short"}).substr(0,15).replace(",",""),
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-navigation-panel ul li button'),
    li_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-navigation-panel ul li'),
    dateTime = document.querySelectorAll('.date-time');

buttons.forEach((item,i)=>{
    if(item.textContent.toLowerCase() == today.substr(0,2)) {
        li_containers[i].classList.add('active');
        dateTime[i].textContent = today.substr(3,15);
    }   
});
```

Исходники полного проекта и весь код на [Github](https://github.com/MrGregor228/schedule)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом приближении, это будет так:

```js
let nowDate = new Date(),
  today = fDate(nowDate),
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-navigation-panel ul li button'),
  li_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.schedule-navigation-panel ul li'),
  dateTime = document.querySelectorAll('.date-time');

function fDate(date, offset = 0) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + offset);
  return date.toLocaleString('ru', {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    year: "numeric",
    weekday: "short"
  }).substr(0, 16).replace(",", "")
}

buttons.forEach((item, i) => {
  if (item.textContent.toLowerCase() == today.substr(0, 2)) {
    li_containers[i].classList.add('active');
  }
  dateTime[i].textContent = fDate(new Date(), (1 + i - (new Date().getDay() || 7))).substr(3, 15);
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap";
button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .schedule-navigation-panel ul li {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) and (max-width: 350px) {
  .schedule-navigation-panel ul li {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) and (max-width: 250px) {
  .schedule-navigation-panel ul li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .schedule-navigation-panel ul li button {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray;
  }
}

.schedule-navigation-panel ul li.active button {
  background-color: #1ba4ee;
  color: white;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel ul li button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  flex-basis: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray, inset 0 0 0px gray, 0px 2px 20px lightgray;
  transition: .15s linear;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel ul li button:active {
  top: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray, inset 0 0 10px gray, 0px 2px 10px lightgray;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel ul li button span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .numerator {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .denumerator {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .numerator,
.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .denumerator {
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .numerator.active,
.schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .denumerator.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .numerator.numerator,
  .schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .denumerator.numerator {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .numerator.denumerator,
  .schedule-navigation-panel .week-cont .denumerator.denumerator {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="schedule-navigation-panel">
  <ul>
    <li><button>Пн<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Вт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Ср<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Чт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Пт<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Сб<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
    <li><button>Вс<br><span class="date-time"></span></button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="week-cont">
    <div class="numerator">Числитель</div>
    <div class="denumerator">Знаменатель</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Просто божественно! Спасибо большое! Этот код будет всё время работать или только для текущей недели?

Comment: @ГригорийКаданер: по задумке, должен работать всегда, если я ничего не упустил. Его ещё можно было бы оптимизировать, да некогда, ну и Вам будет легче разобраться.